# Correlation between two variables.. but does it make sense?

Tags: correlation, spss, bivariate

I'm a grad student and I'm struggling with my first paper. 
I found a correlation between two variables and it turns out to be statistically significant.

The variables are log-transformed. The data is about youtube videos. **ln_viewcount** is the log of **video view counts** and **ln_vidconcept** is the **number of nouns(concepts)** that appear in the title of the video.

I thought that if the title of the video is too long, it would affect the view counts since people tend to avoid long titles. It was just a toy hypothesis, but I tested it and it seems to have a correlation. But I'm not quite sure if the hypothesis really holds...

I even tried a bivariate analysis by controlling several other variables and though the impact is trivial, it seems to be statistically significant.

What else should I have to do to be surer of my hypothesis? I still doubt mine, even after this procedure.. I'm a beginner in statistics, so I would always appreciate elaborate answers. Thanks in advance.

[image: Correlation between variables]

[image: Bivariate analysis]

Comment: You may find an association but you have to be careful not to simply assume that a relationship is casual. There can be a large variety of alternate explanations (for example, that longer titles may tend to go with documentaries or fact-based programs and perhaps it's actually those that people are avoiding). In addition, even the existence or direction of a seemingly significant association is in doubt if there are missing variables that may be relevant (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omitted-variable_bias). These issues are discussed in many posts on site; a site search may help.

Comment: @Glen_b Thank you Glen, for your kind reply :) <br> I have another question.. I found that videos with negative titles have more views than those with positive titles have. But as you explained, the pos/negativity of the content itself may be the actual cause (the omitted variable) for my result. Would it be more reasonable if I check the pos/negativity of the contents? I thought that since videos are clicked by their titles rather than the content itself (since they're experience goods), this would be reasonable enough. (continued in next comment)

Comment: But since you can think of the contents' pos/negativity as an omitted variable, it is very confusing .. Thanks in advance again

Comment: You may want to try searches on omitted variable bias here (or more widely) and (if you're interested in causal conclusions) searches on causality. There's some discussion of methodology relating to both topics here. It may help you refine your question.

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks again. Have a good day!